# My amazon link isn't a 'rad'. Do I have to do that manually?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, status-bydesign

The link to a text on Amazon in my answer here, https://music.stackexchange.com/a/9590/1344 , isn't turning into a 'rad'. Do I have to do something different? I thought they should be automatically replaced.

Comment: What is a "rad"? And could you explain the solution you edited into?

Comment: There's more information [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links). It's a link that tracks click-throughs, so SE gets money when someone buys an item from Amazon through the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Shortlinks aren't converted.**

If you use the full link, in this case [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486460436/ref=cm_sw_su_dp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486460436), it will be.